# Unable to open RStudio-server in web browser

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio-server

I have installed `R` and `Rstudio-server` on `Amazon AMI cloud` and both are running properly as I can type R and get the R-terminal and check whether the RStudio-server is running.

```
sudo lsof | grep rstudio
```

Since Port `8787` is not accessible and there is another port something like `6970` open so I have created a `rserver.conf` file in `/etc/rstudio/` But when I try to open RStudio server from my system's web browser I get this error

```
"No Data Received"
```

I am not sure what is the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using RStudio on AWS instance (EC2, Ubuntu) for several months, so I hope I can help you.  First, could you clarify this part of your post?

> Since Port 8787 is not accessible and there is another port something like 6970 open

I suppose you are using EC2, as it seems to be a common one for this purpose. Then, I believe you can open certain ports by configuring security groups in the AWS console (i.e. Network&Security - Security Group). Have you added a rule to allow 8787 (or 6970 if you prefer) inbound?

Comment: Actually its Amazon AMI instance and I don't have configuration rights. I'll check with my IT team regarding adding the rule and will get back to you on this... thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
rstudio-server online
```